# How do I build and preview latest documentation from Ember.js repository

Tags: ember.js

I have cloned Ember repository

```
git clone git://github.com/emberjs/ember.js.git
```

Then navigate to ember.js directory and run `bundle` and then I try

```
rake docs:build
```

I get this error

```
/home/zooby/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'docs:build'
```

And I get a similar error when I try

```
rake docs:preview
```

What am I missing? How can I build and view the latest version of the documentation available in Ember?

Comment: Check if you have **node.js** installed since you must have it to build the documentation. In addition, you can try to build the preview version of the doc instead with `rake docs:preview` and `docs:preview`.

Comment: `node --version` gives `v0.9.2-pre` so node is installed. As I said in my question `rake docs:preview` gives the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You need to install [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/##install) first.
- Then run `yuidocs` from the **emberjs/docs** folder.
- Open **emberjs/docs/build/index.html** and you're ready to go.

Comment: Make sure to pass along the `-c` argument: `yuidoc -c yuidoc.json`

Comment: The command is now called `yuidoc` instead of `yuidocs`. Check the latest yuidoc info here: http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/##install

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install && npm run docs` to build ember.js documentation.

After that you can running `ruby -run -e httpd docs -p 3000` to visit ember api document at http://localhost:3000/